# how does the characteristic polynomial of a matrix change with respect to the action of taking a principal minor

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix of complex numbers. Let $B$ be the matrix $A$ with the last row and column removed. Is there a relation between the characteristic polynomials of $A$ and $B$? More generally, how does the characteristic polynomial of a matrix change with respect to the action of taking a principal minor?

We can ask the same questions for eigenvalues/eigenvectors, which are closely related with the char polynomial. Intuitively, I feel that the eigenvalues of $B$ are also the eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: How about for instance $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is completely wrong, as simple examples will show.

The best way I can relate the characteristic polynomials is this.  Write 
$$ A = \pmatrix{B & c\cr  d &  e\cr} $$
where $B$ is $(n-1)\times (n-1)$, $c$ is $(n-1) \times 1$, $d = 1 \times (n-1)$, and $e$ is a scalar.  Then

$$ \det(A-\lambda I) = \det(B-\lambda I) (e - \lambda) - d \; \text{adj}(B-\lambda I) c$$
where $\text{adj}$ is the classical adjoint.  In general the term $d \; \text{adj}(B-\lambda I) c$ will be a polynomial of degree $n-2$.